# Loop through geodatabases and list feature classes

Tags: python, sql, loop

Trying to find a way to use Python or SQL to loop through geodatabases and print the feature classes. I'm not sure what the difference between while and for loops are; I'm brand new to scripting. A point in the right direction would be great.

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE!  We're a little different from other sites. We're a Q&A site, not a discussion forum.  For questions that involve code we ask that you show us where you are stuck with your own code by including a [code snippet](http://meta.gis.stackexchange.com/questions/4312) in your question.  There is an [edit] button beneath your question which will enable you to do that and a **`{}`** button that enables you to format any highlighted code nicely.  Please check out our short [tour] for more about how the site works. Thanks.

Comment: Questions about the a Python language itself, including how to use the looping constructs of the language, are off-topic here in GIS SE, where the questions should be GIS-centric. The ArcPy documentation includes examples of using each function. The are also thousands of question/answers here which include code; a google of `arcpy.FunctionName` is likely to return a GIS SE link.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're asking about Esri geodatabases, [arcpy.ListFeatureClasses](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/arcpy/functions/listfeatureclasses.htm) does exactly this given an input workspace (e.g. geodatabase connection).

The code (Python 3) from their example:

```
import arcpy
import os

arcpy.env.workspace = "c:/base/gdb.gdb"

datasets = arcpy.ListDatasets(feature_type='feature')
datasets = [''] + datasets if datasets is not None else []

for ds in datasets:
    for fc in arcpy.ListFeatureClasses(feature_dataset=ds):
        path = os.path.join(arcpy.env.workspace, ds, fc)
        print(path)
```

A **while** loop is used because we don't know how many items there are so the loop continues until it reaches the last item. A **for** loop is used when you want to explicitly determine how many times the loop will be executed.